# Globally set role=button to onkeypress spacebar for pseudo buttons with hrefs

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, accessibility, keypress

We have a giant site with hundreds of pages with many buttons. We are trying to make the site more accessible but nearly all the buttons were originally styled using `<a href=` versus `<button>`. This means we need to enable spacebar to work with these hrefs. My question is can you globally set all links with role="button" to keypress 32 to send the user to the referenced href path using javascript? I know this can be done individually such as:

```
<a href="/employee.html" class="btn" role="button">Example</a>

$(function() {
    $(".btn").keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 32) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location = "/employee.html"
        }
    });
});
```

Is there a way to call a universal keypress 32 for all role=buttons and send the target path to the function so the spacebar will indeed activate the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably try something like the following the target all the links, filter on the ones with the role, and then on the keyup of the space, set the url to whatever href they would normally go to.

```js
$(function() {
    $("a").filter('[role="button"]').on('keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.which === 32) {
            window.location = e.target.href;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something fairly easy even though I just spent hours scouring google and stackoverflow. One note: `e.preventDefault();` should be added above window.location to prevent page scrolling.which is the default action of the spacebar.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure why you had that thrown in there.

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong, page scrolling is activated on keydown, so if I have this script set for keyup it would be after the page already scrolls. I changed it to `.on('keydown',` and get the link functionality while preventing page scrolling.

Comment: Cool.  Only thing with that which is a little weird is the link action will happen before they complete their key interaction.  But maybe that isn't too strange for the user.

Comment: @Taplar @budmaniak I'm not a jquery expert but can't you put the attribute specification on the `"a"` and remove the `filter()`?  Something like `$("a[role='button']").on('keyup'...)`.  That syntax works in CSS so I **think** it works in jquery too.

Comment: You can, however I split it out to allow some optimization with the selector.  `$('a')` will be able to be processed by the native `getElementsByTagName` potentially, where as `$('a[things]`) is not a basic selector and will be forwarded to Sizzle to be processed.  http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/  Later versions may opt to use `querySelectorAll` under the hood, but I still take steps to try to optimize my selectors. @slugolicious